# Catastrophic error during OOB update using CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()

Tags: silverlight

I'm in the dead end with this error, may be someone experienced something similar and knows how to resolve?

The problem is that when calling CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync() the request to the server is sent and server returns either 304 or 200 HTTP code. In case of 200 Silverlight runtime performs update of the application. But it doesn't happen for me. The strange thing is that it works on Mac, but not on Windows.

Request

```
GET https://somedomain.com/some.xap HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 01 Jun 2015 15:13:18 GMT
User-Agent: Silverlight
Host: somedomain.com
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 13:02:36 GMT
X-Request-ID: v-5daa5e84-2a36-11e5-bbce-22000ac00b9d
X-AH-Environment: preprod
X-Cache-Hits: 2
X-Age: 1989
Expires: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:14:18 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:14:18 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
X-Akamai-Staging: ESSL
```

SL Runtime gets valid 200 OK response, but throws catastrophic error message instead of updating the app. From another domain it works though:

Request

```
GET https://somedomain.com/some.xap HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
User-Agent: Silverlight
Host: somedomain.com
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-silverlight-app
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 10:07:05 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "ee4445d61cbed01:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 10:09:04 GMT
Content-Length: 3993496
```

I have already tried changing the content type to application/octet-stream and application/x-silverlight-app on problematic server - nothing. The error is the same. Xap is signed, and, as I said, this works on Mac, not on Windows.

Please, let me know your thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

It was messing the whole Silverlight update experience. The body of the .xap was returned in chunks and Silverlight runtime doesn't like it. Making the server return normal/non-chunked response with content length header set solved the issue.

Cheers.